# Why does admin's template cover over main's one in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

This is my structure.

```
│  run.py
│
├─admin
│  │  views.py
│  │  views.pyc
│  │  __init__.py
│  │  __init__.pyc
│  │
│  └─templates
│          hello.html
│          index.html
│
└─main
    │  views.py
    │  views.pyc
    │  __init__.py
    │  __init__.pyc
    │
    └─templates
            index.html
```

I try to build two apps in flask project. My purpose is when I browse `http://127.0.0.1:5000/main/` it will returns `main/templates/index.html`, when I browse `http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/` it will returns `main/templates/index.html`.

I find I browse `http://127.0.0.1:5000/main/` it will return `main/templates/index.html`. WTF?

If I rename html of different directory when changing `main/templates/index.html` to `main/templates/index2.html`, I am valid to get `main/templates/index2.html` in my expectation

admin/views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
admin = Blueprint("admin", __name__, template_folder="templates")
@admin.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

main/views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
main = Blueprint("main", __name__, template_folder="templates")
@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

run.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from main.views import main
from admin.views import admin

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/main')
app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')

print app.url_map

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is same in django. The document has recommended your template directory should set: `app_name/templates/app_name`.